# mclapply with lme4 and long vectors

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lme4, mclapply

I am using `mclapply` from the `parallel` package to estimate mixed glmer models using the `lme4` package on a high performance cluster. I am having the issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231183/mclapply-long-vectors-not-supported-yet?rq=1). I apply the suggested fix of adding `mc.preschedule=F`, but the problem persists. The code is set up as [described here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/14602_548fb8c68e82402bab53ef718f9a606b.html).

I am not sure how to go around it, any ideas? Should I switch to another method of parallelization? if so, how?

This is my code, but basically it follows the logic of the linked articles:

```
rm(list = ls())

require(lme4)
require(parallel)

load(file="//share//home//eborbath//ess_rescaled.Rda") # load data

# paralelizing function

f_lmer_mc = function(data, calls, mc.cores) {
  require(parallel)
  if (is.data.frame(data)) 
    data = replicate(length(calls), data, simplify = F)
  for (i in 1:length(data)) attr(data[[i]], "cll") = calls[i]
  m.list = mclapply(data, function(i) eval(parse(text = attr(i, "cll"))), 
                    mc.cores = mc.cores, mc.preschedule = FALSE)
  return(m.list)
}

##########
# Models #
##########


controls <- c("gender", "agea", "eduyrs", "domicil", "unemployed", "rideol", "union", "pid", "hincfel")
values <- c("conformity", "universalism", "security")
issues <- c("gincdif", "freehms")
agr.ctrl <- c("gdp_wb_ppp", "wb_vae")
lr.agr <- c("lr_rsquar_std", "ri_l2_std")
val.agr <- c("mean_univ", "mean_conf", "mean_secur")
end <- "1 + (1|cntry/countryyear), data=i, control=glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa', optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e9)), family=binomial(link='logit'))"

models = c(paste0("glmer(protest ~", paste(c(controls, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~", paste(c(controls, values, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~", paste(c(controls, values, issues, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, end), collapse="+")), 
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")), # until here it's only main effects
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*rideol + region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")), 
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*rideol*year + region+year+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")), 
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*rideol*year_num + region+year_num+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")), 
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*soc_pop_eleches + region+soc_pop_eleches+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")), # now come the expl. models
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*rideol*soc_pop_eleches + region+soc_pop_eleches+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*ri_l2_std + region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*ri_l2_std*rideol + region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*lr_rsquar_std + region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*lr_rsquar_std*rideol + region+", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+gov_genlr", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*gov_genlr + region+gov_genlr", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*gov_genlr*rideol + region+gov_genlr", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+pol_galtan", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region+pol_galtan+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*pol_lrecon+region+pol_galtan+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*pol_galtan+region+pol_galtan+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*pol_lrecon*rideol+region+pol_galtan+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")),
paste0("glmer(protest ~ region*pol_galtan*rideol+region+pol_galtan+pol_lrecon", paste(c(controls, values, issues, agr.ctrl, lr.agr, val.agr, end), collapse="+")))

m.list = f_lmer_mc(data, models, 24)

m.1 <- c(m.list[1:3])
m.2 <- c(m.list[4:6])
m.3 <- c(m.list[7:9])
m.4 <- c(m.list[10:12])
m.5 <- c(m.list[13:15])
m.6 <- c(m.list[16:18])
m.7 <- c(m.list[19:21])
m.8 <- c(m.list[22:24])
m.9 <- c(m.list[25:26])

save(m.1, data, file='m_1.RData')
save(m.2, data, file='m_2.RData')
save(m.3, data, file='m_3.RData')
save(m.4, data, file='m_4.RData')
save(m.5, data, file='m_5.RData')
save(m.6, data, file='m_6.RData')
save(m.7, data, file='m_7.RData')
save(m.8, data, file='m_8.RData')
save(m.9, data, file='m_9.RData')
```

This is the relevant error message:

```
Error in sendMaster(try(eval(expr, env), silent = TRUE)) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: fork.c:378
Calls: f_lmer_mc ... mclapply -> lapply -> FUN -> mcparallel -> sendMaster
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The data is a cleaned version of the publicly available [European Social Survey](http://europeansocialsurvey.org). You can download the file from [here](http://www.endre-borbath.eu/stackoverflow/ess_rescaled.Rda) (1.8 MB)

Comment: This is difficult to analyze without the data. Can you reproduce the issue using random data? Otherwise you can run some of the models locally and inspect the resulting objects. Often these objects contain large data sets, which are not strictly necessary further down. In that case you could delete those from the obejct before sending it back to the master.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it's a large dataset. On my machine it takes couple of hours to run any of these models. I have made the data available with a link at the end of the post.

Comment: I see you're replicating the data set and then sending it to all the processes. I haven't done parallel stuff in a while, but you might not need to do that; the vignette says "with mclapply all the packages and objects we use are automatically available
on the workers." If so, that would take care of going to the processes, and Ralf Stubner's suggestion would hopefully take care of coming back.

Comment: To be honest, I am not quite sure how to implement any of these suggestions... meaning cleaning the lme4 output before sending it back or rely on mcapply to take care of the processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this error happens because the forked worker processes are getting an error serializing very large result objects. I've been able to reproduce this error in R 3.3.2 with the following code:

```
library(parallel)
r <- mclapply(1:2, function(i) 1:2^30, mc.cores=2, mc.preschedule=FALSE)
```

However, this example worked for me using a 64-bit build of R 3.4.3, so the serialization limit seems to have been removed (or at least increased) in later versions of R.

I suggest that you either try to reduce the size of the result objects to less than 2GB, or use the most recent version of R.

Comment: thank you! I will ask the cluster administrators to do that!

Comment: @eborbath, for the record and to better help others who report on the same error in the future, with what version of R did you get that error?

Comment: This limitation is documented in R (>= 3.4.0) - in `?parallel::mclapply` it says "Prior to R 3.4.0 and on a 32-bit platform, the serialized result from each forked process is limited to 2^31 - 1 bytes.  (Returning very large results via serialization is inefficient and should be avoided)."

Comment: I have got the error with `R version 3.2.1 -- "World-Famous Astronaut"`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment above:

> I see you're replicating the data set and then sending it to all the
>   processes. I haven't done parallel stuff in a while, but you might not
>   need to do that; the vignette says "with mclapply all the packages and
>   objects we use are automatically available on the workers." If so,
>   that would take care of going to the processes, and Ralf Stubner's
>   suggestion would hopefully take care of coming back.

To try not replicating the data, first have the calls use `data` as read in by your `load` call, instead of `i`; you'd change just this line.

```
end <- "1 + (1|cntry/countryyear), data=data, control=glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa', optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e9)), family=binomial(link='logit'))"
```

Then have `mclapply` just run those, without replicating the data.

```
library(parallel)
m.list = mclapply(calls, function(i) eval(parse(text=i)), 
                  mc.cores = 2, mc.preschedule = FALSE)
```

To try not returning all the information in the models (in particular, the full data set with each model), after looking at the `glmer` output, I think it would be best to do whatever processing you want in the processes, instead of modifying the `glmer` output, as modifying the `glmer` output is likely to make it harder to get the summaries you want afterwards. Here I only get the summary, and put it in a list, so you could add other output easily as well.

```
library(parallel)
m.list = mclapply(calls, function(i) {
                     a <- eval(parse(text=i))
                     list(summary=summary(a))
                  }, mc.cores = 2, mc.preschedule = FALSE)
```

Note that this is all untested...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this!