# Can `sample()` in R just sample in a specified order?

Tags: r, function, random, sampling

I was wondering how I could **generate 1000 integers** from 1 to 1000, one at a time in R. *Making this a function,* this means on the first run of the function, the function should produce `1`, the second run `2`, on the third run `3`, ... `1000`?

**I have tried the following in R with no success:**

```
gen = function(n){
  sample(1:n, 1, replace = FALSE)
  }
gen(1000)
```

Comment: Looks like what you want is something from the iterators [package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16028374/324364).

Comment: This is a horrible idea btw. You may want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Down.voter could you please explain the reason for downvoting this question?

Comment: @rnorouzian, I also have really no idea who downvoted and really why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty bad practice, and you would be better rethinking your plan, but we can do it using a global variable, using `<<-`:

```
myfunc <- function(){
  if(!exists('mycounter')){
    mycounter<<-1
  }else {
    mycounter <<- mycounter + 1
  }
  return(mycounter)
}

> myfunc()
[1] 1
> myfunc()
[1] 2
> myfunc()
[1] 3
> myfunc()
[1] 4
```

You could extend this to eg: index another vector of randoms. Though, set.seed() would probably be want you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen <- function(n)  {replicate(1000,sample(1:n,1))}
```

Comment: I guess you might have misunderstood my purpose, I asked on EACH run of the function ONE number to be generated. That is, the first time you run `gen(1000)`, the function should generate `1`, the second time you run `gen(1000)` it must generate `2`...

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the intent, in fact I still don't understand the intent.

Comment: This is iteration.

Comment: replicate is an iterator....